# Changing name output with ModelBuilder Iterator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, iterator

I have several DEMs where I want to calculate their slope degrees.
I used *iterate rasters* with *slope* tool and I put %Name%_slope as Output Name.
The problem is the Name: it creates a file name too long ("dtm000628_slope")...
I would have slope rasters with name 335_%n%, but "%n%" doesn't work.
Do you know how I could change the name in an rasters iterators?

[image: Here the model]
**The solution is found:

In the output raster, %n% makes a sequential number in the file name of output rasters, but not if you start the file name with a number:

-Example 1:

> in output raster = "C:\Output.gdb\335_slope%n%"

it will **not** work

-Example 2:

> in output raster = "C:\Output.gdb\slope335_%n%"

it will work

-Example 3:

> in output raster = "C:\Output.gdb\s335_%n%"

it will work

Comment: Put error along with, try name started with string not number e.g.`test%n%` instead of `335_%n%`

Comment: The `%%` in model builder is used to refer to within-model variables, such as `Name`. In your case there is no `n` variable, therefore model builder won't get any value if `%n%` is used. Frankly, I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve with `n`.

Comment: @Lion I'm sorry, but it is still quite unclear to me. What were you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "Name is too long as a results" and what are you looking for instead?

Comment: @SIslam, you are right! It works! If you put your comment as answer, I can sign it as the right answer and close this question

Comment: @dof1985 thank you for your helping but I solved. I just wanted to have the possibility to change the name of every single output raster of slope with a new name and not using %Name% because the result was a long file name.

Comment: Well if you would edit your question and add an answer it might benefit future users as well.

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the answer, post it as an actual answer.  Self-answering is fine (and encouraged).  You can then mark it as the answer

Comment: @Lino Ok added answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are wrong with the naming convention of the arcgis featueclass, for details of naming convention get details at the [Defining feature class properties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002200000002000000.htm) of the Online Help.

According to these rules your featureclass name can not be started with numbers.

`%n%` means the loop number in the arcgis model builder.

So your intended name must be like `string+(number)+%n%` e.g. Test_%n%